# Internet issues

Tags: wifi, internet

I have been having issues with internet connectivity for the past week trying to start up elementary os 6. I am new to Linux and am getting to the point of giving up because I'm spinning my wheels and am wasting time. Initially my ThinkpadT14 couldn't find the wifi driver. I found the github workaround (lwfinger/rtw89) for the Realtek 8852AE, which didn't work by itself. Turning off secure boot in addition to the workaround worked for a while, until my PC went to sleep. I am connected to my home network, but no longer have internet. I have tried several of the other workarounds (restarting network manager and radio wifi, etc), but they have not worked. I really want to like elementary since I'm a fan of the macOS, but am at about to pull a U-ie (U-turn) so to speak. Any input is appreciated!

Edit:
Apologies for the pictures. Turns out the PC will not connect to the internet via phone hotspot tethering or ethernet so this was easier than alternatives. Also yes I outed myself as a Canadian with a U-ie reference. Next will come the Gordon Lightfoot lyrics!

lspci command result
[image: sudo lspci result]
lshw -c network result
[image: sudo lshw -c network]

Comment: Wow. A "U-ie"? I haven't heard that term in years. Canadian? Anyway ... could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of the following commands: (1) `sudo lspci` (2) `sudo lshw -c network`. With this, it may be possible to determine what's going on, if you have a correct driver in place, and what the next steps should be 

Comment: Yes Canadians are the best! In getting that information, I realize the computer is not connecting to the internet with any of the connection options.

Comment: When you referred to “the GitHub workaround” earlier, did you mean [lwfinger/rtw89](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89)? If so, have you run [the suspend BIOS fix](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89#problem-with-recovery-after-sleep-or-hibernation)? 

Comment: Yes the Github was lwfinger/rtw89 helped install the driver. I also had to turn off the secure boot, since the install did not work alone. I did not try the suspend BIOS fix before, but in doing it just now and restarting more than once the internet is still not connecting.